# Why doesn't @Qualifier work with @Autowired?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have a class like:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("VeoExecutionService")
public class VeoExecutionService implements ExecutionService {

}
```

and I use it in a test:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("VeoExecutionService")
private VeoExecutionService veoService;
```

But when running I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.trizic.service.veo.VeoExecutionService com.trizic.service.veo.VeoServiceImportAccountsTest.veoService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.trizic.service.veo.VeoExecutionService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=VeoExecutionService)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.trizic.service.veo.VeoExecutionService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=VeoExecutionService)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 31 more
```

Comment: I see no config, and I'm suspicious of whether the service is being loaded in the first place. Remove the qualifier and see if it works.

Answer (score 13):

I think you should use something like:

```
@Service("VeoExecutionService")
public class VeoExecutionService implements ExecutionService {
```

and then, where you inject your service:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("VeoExecutionService")
VeoExecutionService veoExecutionService;
```

Remember to put `<context:annotation-config />` in your xml confing or `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` in java config.

Note that `<context:component-scan />` (`@ComponentScan` in java config) also activates `<context:annotation-config />`

Comment: So the problem had to do with my use of @Transaction in my spring service. Accoridng to Spring docs, it uses JDK dynamic proxies (default) or CGLIB. In the case of JDK proxy it gets confused because the service also implements an interface. I could find no way to deal with this, but after configuring Spring to use CGLIB proxies everything works fine.

Comment: This may seem like the obvious question but they are the ones that often get us, have you ensured that your component scan actually is scaning the location of your service?

Comment: Mine was fixed by putting `<context:annotation-config />` in xml config file

Answer (score 1):

I agree gipinani about the first part

```
@Service("VeoExecutionService")
public class VeoExecutionService implements ExecutionService {
```

But I think the injection part has to be written this way:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("VeoExecutionService")
Private ExecutionService veoExecutionService;
```

in order to inject VeoExecutionService implementation of ExecutionService

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("veoExecutionService")
private VeoExecutionService veoService;
```

"**v**eoExecutionService" (with lower case **v**)